# how do I find what privileges a group has in redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, privileges

I'm having a peculiar problem with one group.
I have revoked all database access for this group
I have revoked all schema access for this group
I have revoked all table access for this group
I have revoked all execute privileges on functions
When I try to drop the group, I get an error saying it cannot be dropped because the group have a privilege on some object.

How can I find out what privileges a group has on redshift?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I remember seeing somewhere that this could be accomplished via terminal on the server. However, you may have the same issue that I had, preventing you from dropping a group. I had default privileges set. I had to do something like this:

```
alter default privileges in schema seeds revoke all on tables from xyz cascade;
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from jbasko was almost right, I've got mine working this way:

```
select 
'alter default privileges for user ' || u.usename || ' in schema '||s.schemaname||' revoke all on tables from group groupname;'
from pg_default_acl d
join pg_user u on d.defacluser = u.usesysid
cross join
    (select distinct schemaname from pg_tables) s
where array_to_string(defaclacl, ',') like '%group groupname=%'
and u.usename = 'some username';
```

Answer (score -1):

You can see the default group privileges in `pg_default_acl` table. It's those entries in `defaclacl` column that are in format `group <groupname>=<privileges>/<grantor>`.

You have to issue the `alter default privileges` for each creating user that the privileges are set for. It's the `defacluser` column which refers to `pg_user.usesysid`.

Replace `groupname` and `schemaname` accordingly and generate the queries to revoke the privileges:

```
select 'alter default privileges for ' || pg_user.usename || ' in schema schemaname revoke all on tables from group groupname;'
from pg_default_acl
join pg_user on pg_default_acl.defacluser = pg_user.usesysid
where array_to_string(defaclacl, ',') like '%group groupname=%';

select 'alter default privileges for ' || pg_user.usename || ' in schema schemaname revoke all on functions from group groupname;'
from pg_default_acl
join pg_user on pg_default_acl.defacluser = pg_user.usesysid
where array_to_string(defaclacl, ',') like '%group groupname=%';
```